# HttpClient not running constructor

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I'm fetching an object from a json endpoint using the HttpClient.  After I fetch it and subscribe to the observable, I found that the constructor doesn't run on the model and the public methods on the object are all undefined.  How do I get the constructor to run and the methods are available?

```
export class Customer {

    constructor() {
        this.Addresses = new Array<Address>();
        }

    public Addresses: Array<Address>;

    public addAddress(address: Address) void{
        this.Addresses.push(address);
    }
}

var url: string = `${this.urlBase}api/customer/${id}`;
var customerObservable: Observable<Customer> = this.authHttp.get<Customer>(url);

customerObservable.subscribe(customer => {
    // Addresses is undefined!
    customer.Addresses.push(new Address());
    // addAddress is undefined!
    customer.addAddress(new Address());
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The data you are getting returned from the .get is in the *shape* of your Customer class (assuming you have properties that are not shown). But is not actually an *instance* of your Customer class.

That is why you can't access any of the Customer class methods.

You'd have to create a Customer instance using the `new` keyword and then copy the data from the get into it.

Something like this:

```
let customerInstance = Object.assign(new Customer(), customer);
```

You are then creating a new instance of the customer and your constructor will execute.

Comment: why not just ```let customerInstance = new Customer(customerResponse);```

Comment: Yup, this did it.  That works similar to AutoMapper in c#.

Answer (score 1):

```
var customerObservable: Observable<Customer> = 
    this.authHttp.get<Customer>(url)
    .map(res => {
         return new Customer()
     });
```

here you can also add/map properties from response to your `new Customer()` instance if you need to.